# AdaBoost in scikit-learn with 1D Weak Learners

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, adaboost, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to replicate some previous work where an AdaBoost classifier was used for a two-class classification problem. There are 75 input dimensions but each weak learner exists in one dimension only.

All of the input values lie in [0,1], and each weak classifier divides this interval into five sub-intervals: [0, 0.2], [0.2, 0.4], ... , [0.8, 1.0].

Within each sub-interval, the weak learner calculates the sum of the weights of all of the samples which have a label "+1", *a*, and the sum of the weights of all of the samples which have a label "-1", *b*.

When we see a piece of test data, we check what sub-interval it falls into, and the weak learner in each dimension outputs 0.5log((*a+epsilon)/(b+epsilon*)) where *epsilon* << *a,b*.

AdaBoost is an iterative algorithm and for each set of sample weights, the algorithm needs to build a weak classifier as described above in every dimension. For each weak classifier we calculate:-

Z = Sum over all sub-intervals of (Total Weight of +1 Labelled Points in this sub-interval * Total Weight of -1 Labelled Points in this sub-interval)^0.5

This value will be small when there is a big difference within each sub-interval of the total weights of each label i.e. when the weak classifier we have designed can discriminate well between +1 labels and -1 labels. The next weak classifier chosen to become part of the strong classifier is the weak classifier with the smallest value of Z for this set of sample weights. We then update the sample weights and choose a new best weak classifier.

I think I can implement the basics of the weak classifier using the BaseEstimator:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_array, check_is_fitted
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

class QuantileMajorityClassifier(BaseEstimator):

def __init__(self,demo_param='demo'):
    self.demo_param = demo_param

def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight):
    """ Assume the input X is 1D because it will be when we use it later"""

    epsilon = 0.000001
    print type(epsilon)

    X = np.reshape(X,(X.shape[0],1))
    y = np.reshape(y,(y.shape[0],1))

    X,y = check_X_y(X,y) # Check X and y have the correctshape

    X = np.reshape(X,(X.shape[0],1))
    y = np.reshape(y,(y.shape[0],1))

    self.classes_ = unique_labels(y) # store the labels seen during fit

    self.X_ = X
    self.y_ = y

    if max(X)>1.0:
        print "Error - Max X > 1.0"
    if min(X)<0.0:
        print "Error - Min X < 0.0"

    X1Indices = np.where(X<0.2)
    X2Indices = np.where((X<0.4) & (X>=0.2))
    X3Indices = np.where((X<0.6) & (X>=0.4))
    X4Indices = np.where((X<0.8) & (X>=0.6))
    X5Indices = np.where((X<=1.0) & (X>=0.8))

    y1=y[X1Indices[0]]
    y1PlusIndices = np.where(y1==1)
    y1MinusIndices = np.where(y1==-1)
    y1PlusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X1Indices[0]][y1PlusIndices])+epsilon
    y1MinusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X1Indices[0]][y1MinusIndices])+epsilon
    y1Fraction = y1PlusWeights/y1MinusWeights
    y1Output = 0.5*math.log(y1Fraction)

    y2 = y[X2Indices[0]]
    y2PlusIndices = np.where(y2 == 1)
    y2MinusIndices = np.where(y2 == -1)
    y2PlusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X2Indices[0]][y2PlusIndices]) + epsilon
    y2MinusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X2Indices[0]][y2MinusIndices]) + epsilon
    y2Fraction = y2PlusWeights / y2MinusWeights
    y2Output = 0.5 * math.log(y2Fraction)

    y3 = y[X3Indices[0]]
    y3PlusIndices = np.where(y3 == 1)
    y3MinusIndices = np.where(y3 == -1)
    y3PlusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X3Indices[0]][y3PlusIndices]) + epsilon
    y3MinusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X3Indices[0]][y3MinusIndices]) + epsilon
    y3Fraction = y3PlusWeights / y3MinusWeights
    y3Output = 0.5 * math.log(y3Fraction)

    y4 = y[X4Indices[0]]
    y4PlusIndices = np.where(y4 == 1)
    y4MinusIndices = np.where(y4 == -1)
    y4PlusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X4Indices[0]][y4PlusIndices]) + epsilon
    y4MinusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X4Indices[0]][y4MinusIndices]) + epsilon
    y4Fraction = y4PlusWeights / y4MinusWeights
    y4Output = 0.5 * math.log(y4Fraction)

    y5 = y[X5Indices[0]]
    y5PlusIndices = np.where(y5 == 1)
    y5MinusIndices = np.where(y5 == -1)
    y5PlusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X5Indices[0]][y5PlusIndices]) + epsilon
    y5MinusWeights = sum(sample_weight[X5Indices[0]][y5MinusIndices]) + epsilon
    y5Fraction = y5PlusWeights / y5MinusWeights
    y5Output = 0.5 * math.log(y5Fraction)

    self.Class1Output_=y1Output
    self.Class2Output_=y2Output
    self.Class3Output_=y3Output
    self.Class4Output_=y4Output
    self.Class5Output_=y5Output

    return self

def predict(self,X):

    X = np.reshape(X,(X.shape[0],1))
    check_is_fitted(self,['X_','y_']) # check that fit has been called

    X = check_array(X) # input validation (just copying from GitHub)

    if max(X)>1.0:
        print "Error - Max X > 1.0"
    if min(X)<0.0:
        print "Error - Min X < 0.0"
    NumberOfTests=X.shape[0]

    TestOutput=np.empty((NumberOfTests,1));
    print TestOutput.T

    for i in range(0,NumberOfTests):
        if X[i] < 0.2:
            TestOutput[i]=self.Class1Output_
        elif X[i][0] < 0.4 and X[i][0]>=0.2:
            TestOutput[i]=self.Class2Output_
        elif X[i][0] < 0.6 and X[i][0]>=0.4:
            TestOutput[i]=self.Class3Output_
        elif X[i] < 0.8 and X[i]>=0.6:
            TestOutput[i]=self.Class4Output_
        elif X[i] <= 1.0 and X[i]>=0.8:
            TestOutput[i]=self.Class5Output_

    return TestOutput
```

And I can get this to behave as I want if I just pass it one dimensional data straight up, although I'm slightly unsure about what I want to return from predict() at this stage.

My question is really when I come to:-

```
TrainingInput=np.arange(20).reshape(10,2)/20.0 # Just some arbitrary data
TrainingLabel = np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=(10,1), p=[1./3, 2./3])
Classifier = AdaBoostClassifier(QuantileMajorityClassifier(demo_param='test'),algorithm="SAMME",n_estimators=2)
Classifier.fit(TrainingInput,TrainingLabel)
```

I get (unsurprisingly) the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/ProjectWork/n-lasr-
project/MajorityClassifierTester.py", line 39, in <module>
Classifier.fit(TrainingInput,TrainingLabel)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\weight_boosting.py", 
line 413, in fit
return super(AdaBoostClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\weight_boosting.py", 
line 145, in fit
random_state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\weight_boosting.py", 
line 477, in _boost
random_state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\weight_boosting.py", 
line 541, in _boost_discrete
estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ProjectWork\n-lasr-
project\QuantileMajorityClassifier.py", line 19, in fit
X = np.reshape(X,(X.shape[0],1))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 232, 
in reshape
return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 57, in 
_   wrapfunc
return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 20 into shape (10,1)
```

**How can I tell AdaBoost that the weak classifiers can only be applied to a single dimension?**

Thanks very much!

Comment: AdaBoost is an iterative process. Each fit of the weak classifier depends on the one preceding it.  Can you clarify your desired behavior?  At each fitting of the weak classifier, how should your method determine which of the 75 input dimensions to fit over?

Comment: @jcrudy See the edit I've just done, hopefully that clarifies things. I've also just updated the Classifier Script to reflect a slightly different form of output for the predictions.

Comment: I understand now.  You'll need to add logic within your weak classifier to compute the value of Z for each dimension and choose the best one.  Your fit method should do this.  Then predict will give the prediction for only the relevant dimension.  You could either edit your current QuantileMajorityClassifier or build something additional that uses the QuantileMajorityClassifier as a component.

Comment: @jcrudy Thanks very much - I've done that now and things seem to be working!